# What liturgical calendar does the Anglican Ordinariate follow?

Tags: catholicism, anglicanism, calendar, liturgical-calendar, anglican-ordinariate

Is the liturgical calendar that the Anglican Ordinariates follow the same as the Novus Ordo (Ordinary Form) calendar, or the Tridentine (Extraordinary Form) calendar, or perhaps it is the same as the calendar used by protestant Anglo-Catholics? Or maybe it is something completely unique?

Answer (score 3):

The Anglican Ordinariate follows the [calendar](http://www.ordinariate.org.au/ordo-november-2015/) of the Ordinary Form of the Mass (Novus Ordo), but does have elements of the Extraordinary Form (Tridentine) calendar incorporated into it.

For the Personal Ordinariate of Our Lady of Walsingham, Wikipedia says this:

> The proper liturgical calendar of the ordinariate was approved by the Congregation for Divine Worship and the Discipline of the Sacraments on 15 February 2012. In the main, it is identical with the current Roman Rite liturgical calendar of the dioceses of England and Wales, but it has retained some elements that form part of the Anglican patrimony. [Personal Ordinariate of Our Lady of Walsingham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Ordinariate_of_Our_Lady_of_Walsingham)

Although the Anglican Ordinaiates have [Ember Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ember_days) and [Rogation Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogation_days#Minor_Rogations), which are elements of the Extraordinary Form, these days have never been abrogated in liturgical reform of Blessed Paul VI and may be still used in the Ordinary Form of the Mass, if desired.